# Ownership of Javascript Object-Properties created via new

Tags: javascript

for example, if i use prototype.js inside my app, the library extends the Objects prototype with some additional stuff, eg:

```
// the code is not exactly like this but that doesnt matter
Object.prototype.inspect = function...
```

when i create some object, the object has NEVER the ownproperty "inspect", which of course is correct:

```
// false
{}.hasOwnProperty('inspect');
```

if i create an Object-literal like this, properties created via this object-literal are ownproperties, which of course is correct too:

```
var myObj = {
   myProp: 'myVal'
};

// this would return true here
myObj.hasOwnProperty('myProp');
```

BUT, if i create an object via the new operator, even the properties inside my Function are not recognized as ownproperty.

```
function MyTest () {}

MyTest.prototype.myProp = function () {};

var myObj = new MyTest();

// this would return false here

myObj.hasOwnProperty('myProp');
```

can somebody explain why it is like that?
i want to iterate over an object, create a new object which only contains properties that are NOT part of the Objects.prototype (and therefore not created through prototype.js).

EDIT: im not the owner of the code that creates myObj, and i dont know which Function-Constructor creates myObj

EDIT2: thanks to niko, thats how i do it now:

```
var key, newObj = {};
for (key in oldObj) {
  if (typeof newObj[key] == 'undefined') {
    newObj[key] = oldObj[key];
  }
}
for (key in newObj) {
  if (newObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // do some stuff here with properties that did not came from the objects.prototype
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sole purpose of `hasOwnProperty` is to tell properties attachted to the actual object (aka the instance) apart from those attached to the prototype. If you construct an instance via the `new` operator, the new instance is linked to the prototype of the function it was constructed from - the properties of the prototype are not copied to the new instance!

Consider something like this to copy everything that is not in Object.prototype:

```
var newObj = {};
for (var key in oldObj) {
    if (typeof newObj[key] == 'undefined') {
        newObj[key] = oldObj[key];
    }
}
```

However, the properties of Object.prototype will still be accessible via `newObj` because it is an instance of, well, Object of course.

Comment: if i understand you correct, it is not possible to check if an objects properties (assuming the object was created via the new operator) came from the Object.prototype or MyTest or whatever class.prototype?

Comment: Well, at least I don't know a solution as easy as a signal function call. If you really need this, you will have to be a bit creative. There is definitely some non-standard stuff that might help here (thinking of the `__proto__` property for example).

Comment: iterating over the object and copying the properties over to a new object really solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because it's assigned to the `prototype`, which in effect is a bit like creating a nebulous class or ancestor for the object, and giving the property to that. The property was never directly assigned to `myObj`.

Worth noting that you could apply the prototype directly to `myObj` rather than its constructor, or apply `myProp` straight to `myTest` without invoking prototype, and `myProp` would still not be `myObj`'s own property.

Comment: thanks for your answer, im not the owner of the code which creates myObj, so part 2 of your answer is not possible for me ;-(. ill add that to my question

Comment: I thought you were just curious as to how it worked — if for some reason you _want_ to be able to get the result `myObj.hasOwnProperty('myProp') === true`, simply re-specify it directly: `myObj.myProp = myObj.myProp`.

Comment: then i need to know that myObj has the property myProp, and thats what i dont know ;-) i need to iterate, and dynamically check which properties came NOT from Object.prototype